Incremental parsing of LLM output
I'm working on a service that calls a Large Language Model, parse the output, and sends the parsed output to a client, message by message. When aggregated, the stream of text coming back from the LLM looks somewhat like this:
This is a reference [r1] and here's an image of a cat <image>a black cat</image>.
I would like to parse this to something like:
[
  {"text": "This is a reference "},
  {"reference": "r1"},
  {"text": " and here's an image of a cat "},
  {"image": "a black cat"},
  {"text": "."},
]

Processing the aggregated stream is not a problem. But processing the stream as messages arrive, is much trickier (for me at least). We must stream text messages as soon as they are ready, buffer non text items, and send them when they are ready.
To make it clear, consider the stream of text coming back like this:
[
  "This ",
  "is ",
  "a ",
  "reference ",
  "[",  # Notice that anything can be broken across different messages
  "r1] ",
  "and ",
  "here",
  "'s ",
  "an ",
  "image ",
  "of ",
  "a ",
  "cat <",  # A more extreme example, breaking messages completely arbitrary
  "ima",
  "ge",
  ">a ",
  "black ",
  "ca",
  "t</i",
  "mage>.",
]

The parsed output should be the following stream of messages:
[
  {"text": "This "},
  {"text": "is "},
  {"text": "a "},
  {"text": "reference "},
  {"reference": "r1"},
  {"text": " "},
  {"text": "and "},
  {"text": "here"},
  {"text": "'s "},
  {"text": "an "},
  {"text": "image "},
  {"text": "of "},
  {"text": "a "},
  {"text": "cat "},
  {"image": "a black cat"},
  {"text": "."},
]

Error handling can be as simple as possible to start with. If we hit [ and never ] just buffer indefinitely. When we hit the end of the stream we can return the buffer as text. If we hit <image> and a closing tag starts with </ but continues with anything but image> return the entire thing as text as well. No need to worry about nested tags for now.
Now, I have some code that does the reference parsing, but it's a very low level python code that is hard to read and is unmaintainable. I tried to look up options for incremental parsing but couldn't find much. That's probably because, as you can read between the lines, my understanding of parsing techniques / tools is very limited. Specifically, I had a quick look at pyparsing, lark, and parsimonious. To be honest, I don't understand most of the terminology to even know if these support something like this.
Given the problem, what are my options? Ideally, what python libraries can I use to solve this problem? If there's some reading to do that you can recommend please share that as well. Don't worry about the LLM part and the asynchronous handling of this. I've got these parts nailed down. I'm only interesting in the incremental parsing.
Thanks!

At their core all parsers are incremental. They go through their input, incrementally, and maintain some state about what they are doing at the moment. I don't know any of the libraries you mention, but I can show how a simple parser looks like, and then you can either use it directly or just get an idea what kind of construct you could be looking for in existing libraries.
The input for a simple parser is a stream of characters, so from this point of view getting a stream of couple-characters doesn't really make a difference.
If your input is called textstream, a corresponding stream of characters would be charstream:
textstream=[
  "This ",
  "is ",
  "a ",
  "reference ",
  "[",  # Notice that anything can be broken across different messages
  "r1] ",
  "and ",
  "here",
  "'s ",
  "an ",
  "image ",
  "of ",
  "a ",
  "cat <",  # A more extreme example, breaking messages completely arbitrary
  "ima",
  "ge",
  ">a ",
  "black ",
  "ca",
  "t</i",
  "mage>.",
]
charstream=(char for fragment in textstream for char in fragment)

Then we can go through the resulting character stream and split it along interesting characters, like [, ], < and >. Here we'll assume "correct" input, something with rectangular brackets is always a reference, something with angled brackets is always a "tag", these characters can't appear anywhere else, and they can't be nested or interleaved.
If that's okay, we can go with 3 variables:
state="text"  # state, can switch to "reference" and "tag"
collector=""  # temporary storage between state changes
parsed=[]     # list of parsed result

And run a very simple loop that

updates state on special characters, collects input otherwise
saves temporary storage into parsed on state change, if it's not empty

A 3.-ish step is that after the input stream ends, the temporary storage may contain something (like a single . in the example text), that has to be saved too.
for character in charstream:
  oldstate=state             # 2. (so we recognize state changes)
  match character:           # 1.
    case "[":
      state="reference"
    case "]":
      state="text"
    case "<":
      state="tag"
    case ">":
      state="text"
    case _:
      collector+=character
  if oldstate!=state and collector:        # 2.
    parsed.append({oldstate:collector})
    collector=""

if collector:               # 3.-ish
  parsed.append({state:collector}) # could be an error if not state is not "text"

import json
print(json.dumps(parsed,indent=2))

This will produce the output (with a couple more line breaks)

[
  {"text": "This is a reference "},
  {"reference": "r1"},
  {"text": " and here's an image of a cat "},
  {"tag": "image"},
  {"text": "a black cat"},
  {"tag": "/image"},
  {"text": "."}
]


Looks like we're getting somewhere, just there's a need for a higher level state tracking if we are in a tag, and what that tag happens to be. If we can still assume that tags aren't nested, we can take quite the shortcut: after entering a tag, there will be a single text (which is then also "all" text), and the next tag is an exit for sure. So a second loop could look like this:
result=[]
tag=""
for element in parsed:
  if "tag" in element:
    if tag=="":           # entering a tag
      tag=element["tag"]
    else:
      tag=""              # it's an exit, could be validated
  else:
    if tag=="":           # we are at top level
      result.append(element)
    else:                 # we use the tag, and also expect "text"
      result.append({tag:element["text"]})

print(json.dumps(result,indent=2))

And it produces the expected output (again cheating with the line breaks):

[
  {"text": "This is a reference "},
  {"reference": "r1"},
  {"text": " and here's an image of a cat "},
  {"image": "a black cat"},
  {"text": "."}
]


Code on Ideone (except for match-case, they're on Python 3.9, so there's a series of if-elif instead). It shows the intermediate output too, the real one is below the horizontal line

Then of course someone could complain about the incremental part. That certainly won't work with two separate loops, so the higher-level state machine has to be moved into the output part of the first loop:
  if oldstate!=state and collector:
    if oldstate=="tag":
      if not tag:  # entering tag
        tag=collector
      else:        # exiting tag, this could be validated
        tag=""
    elif tag:
      print(f'{{"{tag}":"{collector}"}}')
    else:
      print(f'{{"{oldstate}":"{collector}"}}')
    collector=""

# (and tag="" is needed before the loop)

Now the loop produces output as soon as it can with the print lines, so it can consume an actual stream in the pace as it comes.
The character generator can be pimped with printing where it is in the input:
charstream=(char for fragment in textstream for char in (print(f'Input: "{fragment}"'),fragment)[1])

And then the output with interleaved input will look like this:

Input: "This "
Input: "is "
Input: "a "
Input: "reference "
Input: "["
{"text":"This is a reference "}
Input: "r1] "
{"reference":"r1"}
Input: "and "
Input: "here"
Input: "'s "
Input: "an "
Input: "image "
Input: "of "
Input: "a "
Input: "cat <"
{"text":" and here's an image of a cat "}
Input: "ima"
Input: "ge"
Input: ">a "
Input: "black "
Input: "ca"
Input: "t</i"
{"image":"a black cat"}
Input: "mage>."
{"text":"."}


From https://ideone.com/U6lu3C (the after-loop append also became a print, but that's all).
